# Local data (JSON) in Middleman inside a different path than /data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, haml, middleman

I'm working on some templates to generate a static site with several pages. Each one of those pages is inside a different folder, so it will basically be a path similar to "*/source/pages/page-1/index.html.erb*".

What I want to achieve, is to place a data.json file inside the folder "*page-1*" for example, and extract its content into the *index.html.erb* file in the same folder, using Middleman. The problem is that Middleman requires all of the .json files to be inside "*/data*", and I need each data.json file to be inside its own folder.

Is there a way to make Middleman extract each .json file individually for each folder?

I hope I was clear enough. Any help will be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try writing a helper method that locates, loads and parses de JSON data for the current page. I haven't actually tested this, but I guess it would look something like this:

```ruby
# config.rb

helpers do
  def json_data(filename = "data.json")
    container_dir = File.split(current_resource.path).first.split(File::SEPARATOR).first
    json_path = File.join(source, container_dir, filename)
    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(IO.read(json_path))
  end
end
```

Comment: I've already decided to put all of the information inside "/data" as an array, and extract it inside each page, but this may be just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to make something like this. Looks like the the directory is defined [here](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/2426abe6f5fb2e5019840dfa1648a98e58bfb871/middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/data.rb#L14).

BUT! you should be able to change the location of the entire data directory:

```
set :data_dir, 'source/data'
after_configuration do
  data.categories.each do |category, data|
    proxy "/#{category}.html", "/category.html", locals: {category: data}
  end
end
```

The reason why it's like this is to group all the data in one place.

You can make something like:

```
data
|-- page1
|    |-- content1.yml
|    +-- content2.yml 
|
|-- page2
|    |-- content1.yml
|    +-- content2.yml
.
.
```

and extract it using `data.page1.content1`.

I'm looking forward to see if someone comes with a hack.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, radubogdan. If nothing comes up I'll probably end up doing something like that.